# Finding min value of exponential expression.

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

> Let $x,y, z$ be reals such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$. What is the minimum value of $2^{1/x}+2^{1/y}+2^{1/z}$?

First I thought taking $x,y,z$ as $-1$ which leads to $3/2$. However by trial and error, if I take $x=y=-1.1$ then $z=-\sqrt{0.58}$. In that case I get a value of the expression $1.468<1.5$, so clearly what I took first is wrong.

So how to go about solving this?

Comment: **Note**: There is no global minima, but there are several local minimas.

Comment: We can say defnintely that min>0. Also by trial and error it is clear that 3/2 is not the min.. I have a hunch that min will occur when y,z are negative numbers very close to zero. Then if x tends to -root(3).